# Why am I getting an attribute error with object has no attribute get, in django?

Tags: python, html, django

Models.py:

```
class WeeklyPlan(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Weekly Plan Name")
    monday = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="monday_plans")
    tuesday = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="tuesday_plans")
    wednesday = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="wednesday_plans")
    thursday = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="thursday_plans")
    friday = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="friday_plans")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import WeeklyPlan, Extra, Meal
# Create your views here.


def homepage(request):
    plans = WeeklyPlan.objects.all()
    print(plans)
    context = {"plans": plans}
    return render(request, template_name='food/index.html', context=context)
```

I would've expected this to output all the weekly plan objects but instead got the error:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rayyan Admin\Documents\GitHub\food_delivery\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rayyan Admin\Documents\GitHub\food_delivery\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 138, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Rayyan Admin\Documents\GitHub\food_delivery\venv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 27, in process_response
    if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None:
AttributeError: 'WeeklyPlan' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Can anyone assist me on this?

EDIT:
I am adding my html file as well; which is just a boilerplate:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems that somewhere you are trying to access a WeeklyPlan `instance.get`, and there is no such attribute on your model. Could you share your template?

Comment: I have added the template, but it was just a boilerplate html

Comment: That is very odd, seems to be failing on the [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/clickjacking/#how-to-use-it) somehow. I am having problems in replicating the issue. Could you check its presence in `settings.py`?